# Extract values of lists based on other list R

Tags: r, list, select

Given three `lists` `A`, `B`, and `C`, containing `crop yields` and their `latitudes` and `longitudes`, respectively. Each `dataframe` in the `lists` has different number of columns, **but the three lists have equal dimensions**.

I would like to apply a function, say to get the `max` in each row in `A`:

```
S=lapply(A, function(x) apply(x, 1, max))
```

**Question**: How can I get the corresponding values in `B` and `C`and their `column indexes e.g. which.max` such that I can say the `max` crop yield in `A`was at `latitude Y` and `longitude X`?

I will then make a dataframe containing columns `A.max`, `Lat`, `Lon`

Other ways to merge the three lists for easy indexing are welcome.

Thank you.

```
A =list(structure(46952.8457255653, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(125267.690717471, 
    72379.4321037455, 72468.9078338802, 13200.2611700977), .Dim = c(1L, 
    4L)), structure(c(26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 
    26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 19898.5698162604, 26513.0496549167, 
    26513.0496549167), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(19814.7410087512, 
    39570.9565633454), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(52291.7656702341, 
    52291.7656702341), .Dim = 1:2))

B =list(structure(15.3210227272727, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(18.5599762470309, 
18.8800251256281, 18.6755033557047, 18.3664122137405), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(c(17.625, 17.625, 17.625, 17.625, 17.6262295081967, 
17.5, 17.625, 17.625), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(18.25, 
18.4964285714286), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(19.9533582089552, 
19.9633204633205), .Dim = 1:2))

C= list(structure(-84.1903409090909, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(-102.525534441805, 
-104.263190954774, -103.906711409396, -103.88358778626), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(c(-77.6250000000001, -77.6250000000001, -77.6250000000001, 
-77.6250000000001, -77.6262295081967, -77.5, -77.625, -77.625
), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(-69.2391304347826, -69.6303571428571
), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(-75.8619402985075, -75.8513513513514
), .Dim = 1:2))
```

Comment: Thank you all for the wonderful solutions. All of them helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `tidyverse` tools. Here we're using the fact that the lists have the same dimensions to place them into a `tbl` and `unnest` them, so we have one row per observation of `yield`, `lat` and `long`. We have to first convert all the one-row matrices into vectors to do this using `map(as.vector)` though. Once the data is in this format, it is a simple `group_by` and `summarise` to get one value per original list element.

```r
library(tidyverse)
A =list(structure(46952.8457255653, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(125267.690717471, 
72379.4321037455, 72468.9078338802, 13200.2611700977), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(c(26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 
26513.0496549167, 26513.0496549167, 19898.5698162604, 26513.0496549167, 
26513.0496549167), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(19814.7410087512, 
39570.9565633454), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(52291.7656702341, 
52291.7656702341), .Dim = 1:2))

B =list(structure(15.3210227272727, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(18.5599762470309, 
18.8800251256281, 18.6755033557047, 18.3664122137405), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(c(17.625, 17.625, 17.625, 17.625, 17.6262295081967, 
17.5, 17.625, 17.625), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(18.25, 
18.4964285714286), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(19.9533582089552, 
19.9633204633205), .Dim = 1:2))

C= list(structure(-84.1903409090909, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), structure(c(-102.525534441805, 
-104.263190954774, -103.906711409396, -103.88358778626), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(c(-77.6250000000001, -77.6250000000001, -77.6250000000001, 
-77.6250000000001, -77.6262295081967, -77.5, -77.625, -77.625
), .Dim = c(1L, 8L)), structure(c(-69.2391304347826, -69.6303571428571
), .Dim = 1:2), structure(c(-75.8619402985075, -75.8513513513514
), .Dim = 1:2))

tibble(
  row = 1:length(A),
  yields = map(A, as.vector),
  lat = map(B, as.vector),
  long = map(C, as.vector)
) %>%
  unnest(yields, lat, long) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(
    A.max = max(yields),
    lat = lat[which.max(yields)],
    long = long[which.max(yields)]
    )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     row   A.max   lat   long
#>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  46953.  15.3  -84.2
#> 2     2 125268.  18.6 -103. 
#> 3     3  26513.  17.6  -77.6
#> 4     4  39571.  18.5  -69.6
#> 5     5  52292.  20.0  -75.9
```

Created on 2018-04-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from `B` and `C` based on the indices where the max values occur in `A` using [`map`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) & [`map2`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) from `purrr` (part of the `tidyverse`).

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(A.max = map_dbl(A, max)) %>% 
    mutate(Lat = map2(B, map(A, which.max), `[[`), 
           Lon = map2(C, map(A, which.max), `[[`))

#       A.max      Lat       Lon
# 1  46952.85 15.32102 -84.19034
# 2 125267.69 18.55998 -102.5255
# 3  26513.05   17.625   -77.625
# 4  39570.96 18.49643 -69.63036
# 5  52291.77 19.95336 -75.86194
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer in base R:

```
max.indices <- sapply(A, which.max)
A.max <- sapply(A, max)
Lat <- sapply(seq_along(B), function(i) B[[i]][max.indices[i]])
Lon <- sapply(seq_along(C), function(i) C[[i]][max.indices[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base r option:

```
S=sapply(A, function(x) apply(x, 1, which.max))
f <- function(x,y) x[y]
g <- function(x) mapply(f,x,S)
> mapply(rbind,g(A),g(B),g(C))
            [,1]         [,2]      [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] 46952.84573 125267.69072 26513.050 39570.95656 52291.76567
[2,]    15.32102     18.55998    17.625    18.49643    19.95336
[3,]   -84.19034   -102.52553   -77.625   -69.63036   -75.86194
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant on @cmaher's answer, removing the nested `map` statments.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(max_yield = map_dbl(A, which.max)) %>% 
  transmute(crop_yield =  map2_dbl(B, max_yield, ~.x[which.max(.y)]),
            latitude = map2_dbl(B, max_yield, ~.x[which.max(.y)]),
            longitude = map2_dbl(C, max_yield, ~ .x[which.max(.y)]))

  # A tibble: 5 x 3
  crop_yield latitude longitude
       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1       15.3     15.3    - 84.2
2       18.6     18.6    -103  
3       17.6     17.6    - 77.6
4       18.2     18.2    - 69.2
5       20.0     20.0    - 75.9
```

Comment: Doesn't this get the max value from each list in each row, rather than the ones in B and C corresponding to the max in A?

Comment: @CalumYou it does. great solution. I can only accept one answer as solutions are provided.

Comment: @CalumYou, spaced on that requirement, fixed now, which makes it a variant of cmaher's solution